# c# read the value of a changing Progressbar in webbrowser

Tags: c#, progress-bar, webbrowser-control

I am kinda new to c# (spent my time in delphi before) and I am having trouble finding this out:

the Html code of the website is this:

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" id="counter" style="width: 10.%; overflow: hidden;"></div>
```

I am trying to figure out sth like this:

```
var CheckValue = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("counter"); if (counter.style.width > 70%) { //code }
```

So basically what im trying to do is:
I want to check if the width of the progressbar on the website ist filled by more than 70% and if it is it shall execute a code but if it isnt it shall try again after a few seconds.

If you need any more information just tell me!

Thanks

Comment: You don't have any variable `counter`. You can use `CheckValue.Style`, which will return a string containing the style.

Comment: thank you for your answer! how can i then only take the value of the width from the progressbar cause I only need that one?

Comment: You can use regex for that. You need to find the value between `width: ` and `%`. If you have that and convert it into an integer, you can see if it is higher than 70.

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try it out now :)

Comment: Hey I go this Code here: https://gyazo.com/9a3fe232a3360e9032a4d0ac3e9069f1
but I am still getting an error and i dont know what could be wrong :( @Ivar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`CheckValue.Style`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.style(v=vs.110).aspx), which will return a string containing the style. Then you can use [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) to find what you are looking for.

You want your regex to match the digits between the `width:` and the `.%`. You can use this for that:

```
width: ([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)\.?%
```

This will match every string starting with `width:` and ending with `%` with the possibility of a `.` before the `%`, with at least 1 character between 0 and 9.

You can use this code to get this value:

```
var checkValue = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("counter");

Regex regex = new Regex("width: ([0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)\\.?%");
Match match = regex.Match(checkValue.Style);

// Check if match found
if (match.Groups.Count > 1)
{
    String s = match.Groups[1].ToString();
    int width = (int)Convert.ToDouble(s);
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much! I just have two questions left :S

If the number before the "%" is something like this 72.3213% will the code still function as intended (me getting the number before the dot?)

And for me it says at line 4 of yor code that I "cannot convert from System.WIndows.Forms.HtmlElement to String.

Couldnt find any solution on the Internet :( you have an idea of what it might be ?

Thank you!

Comment: You are right. The regex did not take floating numbers into a count, and it would crash. I just fixed it. And I forgot the `.Style` behind the `checkValue`, which caused that error you got.

Comment: Thank you for editing the Code! As I stated the Number is followed by some digits after the dot. 

First of all: Your regex "search" (?) doesnt function (I tested it on http://myregexp.com/ with athe number I wrote 2 comments ago and it got no results :). 

But i found the proper solution ! :D it is `width: ([0-9]+).([0-9]+)?%` and I get three matches! 

Sooo I actually only care about the group #1 (on the site its the 72) becuase I these floating numbers are kinda irrelevant. Now I kinda have trouble only getting group #1 :|
Thanks

Comment: Edited the regex again. It should work that way now. The `(int)Convert.ToDouble(s)` casts a double to an integer with the same result. Your regex does have a flaw: The `.` in your regex means it matches any character. If you want to match a `.` you should escape it like this: `\.`. (And in C# you need to escape `\` as well so it will become `"\\."` in your string. But even if you do this, it means that you are required to have a `.` in your width, so you probably want to make it optional as well with the `?`: `\.?`.

Comment: Also `([0-9]+)?` == `[0-9]*`. (`+` means 1 or more characters and the `?` means optional, where `*` means 0 or more characters.

Comment: Hey! I tried your regex online again and (https://gyazo.com/304f15f9b8691a87d17064a642c59e71) your new regex doesnt work :P but your last comment helped very much! I replaced the `([0-9]+)?` with the `[0-9]*` and put up an extra label just to see what number I am getting and it only gives me the number before the dot (exactly what I need) so the new regex is : `width: ([0-9]+).[0-9]*%` :)

Comment: @root Use the one above the code. The one you copied is from the string, and that one has double backslashes to escape them. (You can't use `\\` directly in a C# string literal.) [See an example here.](https://regex101.com/r/jM2rW9/1)

Comment: You are right! Im sorry! Thank you for all your help !